# I want to calculate electricity bill with units in php

Tags: php

This is my scenario:

- if units are <= 100 then charge Rs 1 rupee/unit
- if units are > 100 && <= 200 then charge Rs 2 rupee/unit
- if units are > 200 && <= 300 then charge Rs 3 rupee/unit
- if units are > 300then charge Rs 7 rupee/unit

  ```
  if($units > 100){
  $bill = 100 * 1;
  $remaining_units= $units  -100;

  if($remaining_units > 100 ){
      $remaining_units= $remaining_units  -100;
      $bill = $bill +  (100* 2);
      if($remaining_units > 100 || $remaining_units < 100){
           $remaining_units= $remaining_units  -100;
          $bill = $bill +  (100* 3);

          if($remaining_units > 100 || $remaining_units < 100){

              $bill = $bill +  (100* 7);
          }
      }
  }
  }
  echo $bill;
  ```

Comment: what you tried so far,what you want exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack. put your code what you want todo

Comment: Are you expecting SO to just give you the code? That's what software developers are for. Hire one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because op is just asking for code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to place code with question

Comment: Try using `else if` instead of `ifs`

Comment: If there are 300 units do they all get charged at 3 or the first 100 get charged at 1?

Comment: first 100 charged 1, and second 100 charged 2 and third 100 charged 3 and other charge rate is 7

Comment: But what does it mean `$bill = $bill +  (100* 2);` ? In the second part ?

Comment: Your `if($remaining_units > 100 || $remaining_units < 100)` should be `if($remaining_units > 100)` in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function this function will work for you:

```
echo calculate_bill(210);

    function  calculate_bill($units, $multipler = 1, $oldBill=0){
        if($units > 100){
            $remainingUnits = $units -100;
            $oldBill = (100 * $multipler) + $oldBill;           
        }else{
             $a = ($units * $multipler) + ($oldBill);
             return $a;
        }
        /*first level complete*/            
        if($multipler == 1){ 
            $multipler = 2;
        }elseif($multipler == 2){
            $multipler = 3;
        }elseif($multipler >= 3){ 
            $multipler = 7;
        }
        return calculate_bill($remainingUnits,$multipler, $oldBill);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya its working fine now

```
if($units < 100){
        $bill = $units*1;
    }elseif($units > 100 && $units <=200){
        $temp = 100*1;
        $remaining_units = $units - 100;
        $bill = $temp + ($remaining_units *2);
    }elseif($units > 200 && $units <=300){
        $temp = (100*1)+ (100*2);
        $remaining_units = $units - 200;
        $bill = $temp + ($remaining_units *3);
    }else{
        $temp = (100*1)+ (100*2)+ (100*3);
        $remaining_units = $units - 300;
        $bill = $temp + ($remaining_units *7);
    }

    echo $bill;
```